# How to make Dynamic css path?

Tags: php

I'm using not_found.php file for unfound files on server , and it's in Main Directory

it's style is in 'assests/css/main.css' from same Directory ,

so I make href of linking stylesheet

```
href="assests/css/main.css"
```

it works perfect if user types 'Main/wrongFile' for example , but if user typed 'Main/ez/wrongFile' , stylesheet is included wrongly due to changing of path

I'm searching for function like

```
$Path = FindPath('Main/assests/css/main.css');
```

so it gets that path wherever file is in

then I can simply

```
href="<?php echo $Path; ?>"
```

Comment: Just use an absolute href i.e. `href="/Main/assests/css/main.css"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to fix it is using the code below;

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assests/css/main.css" type="text/css"/>`

adding `/` at beginning of `assests/css/main.css` simply tells browsers which root directory to look at.

**Option 2)** Using htaccess. Add the code below into your .htaccess file

`RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/assests/css/main.css$ assests/css/main.css [R=301,L,NC]`